# Как правильно инициализировать Retrofit в MVP?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

В интернете нашёл два пути решения проблемы инициализации Retrofit. Как я понял, он должен быть Singleton.
Если я использую MVP в своём проекте, то с точки зрения архитектуры и SOLID разумнее будет выделить отдельный класс-singleton для инициализации Retrofit и потом с помощью Dagger 2 инжектить его в свои активити/фрагменты или же тупо инициализировать Retrofit в классе App, который наследует от Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создайте отдельный модуль. Например `NetworkModule`.
2. В нём сделайте методы с `@Provide` аннотацией, которые будут возвращать Retrofit, OkHttp и прочие нужные вещи.
3. Используйте модуль в компоненте.
4. Инжектите куда нужно. При этом желательно обернуть это в репозиторий/интерактор

Comment: благодарю. Если же создать класс в котором метод будет возвращать инициализированный Retrofit, то это будет нормальной практикой ?По идее можно же в самом @Provides инициализацию провести

Comment: Не очень понял что вы имеете в виду. По идее надо из @Provides метода вернуть экземпляр ретрофита, созданного через билдер

Comment: вот вопрос в том, где создавать лучше ретрофит. Прямо в @Provides методе или отдельный класс для него завести. С точки зрения чистого кода как лучше будет?

Comment: Отдельного класса не надо. Можно Singleton аннотацию повесить на метод. И ещё добавить метод с Provides аннотацией для интерфейса, в котором методы описаны. И именно его уже и инжектить. Сам ретрофит инжектить никуда не надо